# Emacs stopped exporting org files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using Emacs 24.4 and org-mode 8.2.10 (I can't understand why I can't update it to the last version 8.3.1. My version is the last in ELPA but when I ask for org-version I get 8.2.10).
The fact is that now I cannot export any org file to any type of file. The error message is `Symbol's value as variable is void: org-planning-line-re`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion would be to reinstall Org from a new instance of emacs in which your current copy of Org is not loaded.

It seems, based on your description, that Org 8.3.1 was installed from Elpa while your existing copy of Org (8.2.10) was active, which resulted in a corrupted installation.

Comment: I have already deleted my elpa folder `org-20150810` and reinstalled org from elpa after with no effect. What do you mean by new instance of emacs? A new installation of emacs?

Comment: Try this.  After installing from elpa, run `C-u M-x org-reload` to load the uncompiled files.  Then uninstall and reinstall Org using `package-list-packages`.

Comment: Well I did all that with no effect. But...when I simply did `M-x org-reload` everything seems to work fine. The org version is now 8.3.  The only problem to export to pdf is that LaTeX uses a style file not found (coming from Kieran Healy Emacs-starter-kit). But now I can export to markdown.

Comment: New problem: I have to do `M-x org-reload` every time I need to export an org file. What is happening?

Comment: I think now it is solved with a new installation of org using this [help](http://sachachua.com/blog/2014/05/update-org-7-comes-emacs-org-8-configuration-better-exports/).

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be happening because you are loading `org` package from system installation then loading it again from local installation (e.g. from a ELPA repository).

Double check if your have any `(require 'org)` before `(package-initialize)`.